# PDFReactor not mapping paragraph/image tags correctly

Tags: accessibility, pdf-reactor

I am using PDFReactor to create accessible PDF documents from html documents. I am using PAC3 to validate the PDFs for accessibility. PAC3 has a screen reader preview feature that displays a visual representation of the structure of the document from a screen reader's perspective.
I've noticed that surprising often the screen reader view will display the document with what were definately html "p" tags as PDF "Div" tags. It also has converted html "img" tags to PDF "Div" tags containing "Alt" tags instead of the expected "Figure" tag containing an "Alt" tag.
I realize the problem may be with PAC3 screen reader preview, but is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: PDFreactor automatically tags HTML elements according to certain criteria. Usually, HTML <p> elements are tagged as “P” and <img> elements are tagged as “Figure”. To analyze what's wrong, it would be great to have a sample document (HTML+CSS) to reproduce this issue.